# using htaccess to redirect http and https based on conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I want to redirect everything except an url to HTTPS and redirect the specific url to HTTP

I used the following apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/url
    RewriteRule ^ https://mydomain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/url
    RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Unfotunately it just loop forever in the redirections and I can't figure out the correct rewritecond conditions to make it work properly

**UPDATE**:

I also have these rules beside that might influence something I guess... :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    DirectorySlash Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have more rules besides these 2?

Comment: I updated the post with the mod_rewrite conditions that might alter the behaviours

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rearrange your rules:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains"
</IfModule>

DirectorySlash On
Options -Multiviews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^url https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^url http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I still got the same problem... :( I tried to clear the browsing history & cache etc but no luck...

Comment: I made some updated, try updated code and test in a new browser.